# 2006 Smart Fortwo: Key fob stopped working after disconnecting the battery

Tags: battery, fob, smart-car

I own a 2006 Smart Fortwo Pure (Diesel) and had to disconnect the battery recently because the parking lights wouldn't turn off (issue resolved now; most probably moisture in control lever). When I connected the battery again, the key fob stopped working. None of the 3 buttons work. The problem is that the car is now in safe mode and it won't start (exit safe mode) unless I unlock it using the fob. Any suggestions on how to override the safe mode without the fob or how to get the fob to work again would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you followed the fob programming procedure for your car?

Comment: @SolarMike I did not. Can I do it myself? Or do I need to visit the dealership? Couldn't find anything of that sort in the owner's manual

Comment: Tried googling wth key words like '06 Smart Four Two Pure remote programming'? Searched for Smart forums with members possibly more informed about Smart cars?